# Visual Studio + Cross Platform OpenGLES 2 Project Bug/issues

Tags: visual-studio

I opened visual studio 2015, installed the cross-platform stuff(android, etc). Was 10GB worth of stuff. Created a new project using OpenGLES 2 for android IOS and windows.

I get errors on project creation and a few warnings:

[image]

Error (active)      identifier "**SIZE_TYPE**" is undefined OpenGLESApp2.Android.StaticLibrary

Error (active)      identifier "**PTRDIFF_TYPE**" is undefined  OpenGLESApp2.Android.StaticLibrary

Error (active)      more than one instance of overloaded function "__builtin_isnanf" has 'C' linkage

Error (inactive)        cannot open source file "Availability.h"    OpenGLESApp2.iOS.StaticLibrary

I did absolutely no modification of the project. This all happens when VS is creating the project from the template.  When I tried to install the cross platform stuff, VS said something wasn't able to install(I think the android emulator or something). (I do have android studio installed so I don't know why all that stuff needed to be redownloaded(the SDK, etc)).

Any ideas?